# Could an adjective be used like an adverb in Latin?

Tags: adjective, adverb

As a general rule, could an adjective be used like an adverb in Latin?

What would be some exceptions?

Comment: Does the info in [this other question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7038/agreement-in-medio-tutissimus-ibis/) help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three main ways to turn an adjective into an adverb in Latin. In decreasing order of popularity:

- Use a special adverb-forming suffix: first/second adjectives get *-ē*, while third adjectives get *-ter*. This can be done freely to pretty much any adjective (*famōsē*, *rubrē*, *calidē*, *velociter*, *prūdenter*).
- Use the neuter accusative form. This is also quite well-attested, but less productive; it's where third comparative adverbs in *-ius* and (non-comparative) adverbs in *-e* come from (*facilius*, *facile*, *multum*).
- Use the neuter ablative form. This one was dying out by Classical times, mostly showing up in set phrases and fossilized expressions, but it's the ancestor of the extremely common *-ē* mentioned above (*verō*, *falsō*).

The first at least was still productive in Classical times; I'm not aware of any adjectives which couldn't be turned into adverbs in one way or another.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning instances where Latin uses adjectives, esp. in the nominative, where we would more naturally use an adverb in English – e.g., tacitus venit, 'He came in silence/silently', laeti audiverunt, 'they listened with joy/happily.'

Comment: @cnread You could also mention those in a separate answer. There's nothing wrong with having multiple answers with different focuses or points of view. Even different wordings of the same idea can be very useful.

Comment: Group **1** Adverbial suffix, includes the group *gradatim,* step by step; *seriatim,* one-by-one; *sparsim,* here and there; etc. (just for completenes; does not affect the adj. for adverb Q.&A.)