# Chosing between the different ways to make an adverb

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, grammar-choice, adverb

I was thinking of translating “That is not dead which can eternal lie” into Latin for fun, thinking it was not only applicable to Cthulhu, but to the Latin language itself :)

But I got stumped trying to pick the adverb. As described in [Could an adjective be used like an adverb in Latin?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/12694/could-an-adjective-be-used-like-an-adverb-in-latin#answer-12695), there are 3 ways to turn an adjective into an adverb in Latin, but I am unsure if all 3 ways are applicable to all adjectives, nor whether they mean the same thing.

> Id nōn est mortuum quod aeternō iacere potest.

> Id nōn est mortuum quod aeternē iacere potest.

> Id nōn est mortuum quod aeternum iacere potest.

Are all three valid? If not, why not? If yes, what's the difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like *aeternē* was rarely used in Classical Latin. The PHI corpus shows only three matches, two of which are in grammatical discussions explaining that *aeternum* means *aeternē.*

The third is in Cicero *De Natura Deorum* 1.109.6:

> quo modo enim probas continenter imagines ferri, aut si continenter, quo modo **aeterne**?

The Lewis and Short entry for *[aeternus](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/aeternus)* has an entry for adverbial expressions that mentions *aeternum* and *aeternō*, and also the phrase *in aeternum*:

> Adv. phrases.
>
> 1. **in aeter-num.**
>
>    A Lit., ***forever, everlastingly:*** et vivat
>    in aeternum, Vulg. Gen. 3, 22: hoc nomen mihi est in aeternum, ib.
>    Exod. 3, 15: Dominus in aeternum permanet, ib. Psa. 9, 8: vivet in
>    aeternum, ib. Joan. 6, 52: Tu es sacerdos in aeternum, ib. Heb. 5, 6:
>    non habebit remissionem in aeternum, ib. Marc. 3, 29.—
>
>    B Meton., of
>    indef. long time, ***forever, always:*** urbs in aeternum condita, Liv. 4,
>    4: leges in aeternum latae, id. 34, 6: (proverbia) durant in aeternum,
>    Quint. 5, 11, 41: delatores non in praesens tantum, sed in aeternum
>    repressisti, Plin. Pan. 35: (famulos) possidebitis in aeternum, Vulg.
>    Lev. 25, 46: (servus) serviet tibi usque in aeternum, ib. Deut. 15,
>    17: ut sceleris memoria maneat in aeternum, Lact. 1, 11.—
> 2. **aeternum.**
>
>    A Lit., ***forever:*** sedet aeternumque sedebit Infelix Theseus, Verg. A.
>    6, 617: ut aeternum illum reciperes, Vulg. Phil. 15 (prob. here an
>    adv.).—
>
>    B Meton., of indef. long time, ***forever, always***: serviet
>    aeternum, Hor. Ep. 1, 10, 41.—
>
>    C Of what is continually repeated,
>    ***constantly, again and again*** (as in colloq. Engl., ***everlastingly,
>    eternally***): glaebaque versis Aeternum frangenda bidentibus, Verg. G.
>    2, 400: ingens janitor Aeternum latrans (of Cerberus), id. A. 6, 401.—
> 3. **aeternō**, meton., of indef. long time, ***forever, perpetually***: viret
>    aeterno hunc fontem igneum contegens fraxinus, Plin. 2, 107, 111, §
>    240: BVSTA TVTA AETERNO MANEANT, Inscr. Orell. 4517.

I don't have enough reading experience in Latin to have a sense for the differences, but a more experienced Latinist, Kingshorsey, made the following observation in a Reddit post:

> The most common adverbial form is *in aeternum,* followed by *aeternum* and *aeterno.*

([2019/1/23 reply to "Translation request: Licet amētis permansimus, nunc, et aeternum."](https://www.reddit.com/r/latin/comments/aj2zuh/comment/eesuvpk/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3))